# Regular Expression: Find a specific group within other groups in VB.Net

Tags: regex, string, vb.net, replace, regex-group

I need to write a regular expression that has to replace everything except for a single group.

E.g

| IN | OUT |
| --- | --- |
| OK THT PHP This is it 06222021 | This is it |
| NO MTM PYT Get this content 111111 | Get this content |

I wrote the following Regular Expression: `(\w{0,2}\s\w{0,3}\s\w{0,3}\s)(.*?)(\s\d{6}(\s|))`

This RegEx creates 4 groups, using the first entry as an example the groups are:

1. OK THT PHP
2. This is it
3. 06222021
4. Space Charachter

I need a way to:

- Replace Group 1,2,4 with String.Empty

OR

- Get Group 3, ONLY

Comment: Please show the code you have. Can you modify the code, BTW? Capturing group are used to either *extract* some "interesting" substring from a match, or to keep some part of a match when replacing. They are NOT meant to mark some part of string for deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 4 groups, you can use a single group 1 to be in the replacement and match 6-8 digits for the last part instead of only 6.

Note that this `\w{0,2}` will also match an empty string, you can use `\w{1,2}` if there has to be at least a single word char.

```
^\w{0,2}\s\w{0,3}\s\w{0,3}\s(.*?)\s\d{6,8}\s?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\w{0,2}\s\w{0,3}\s\w{0,3}\s` Match 3 times word characters with a quantifier and a whitespace in between
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 1** match any char as least as possible
- `\s\d{6,8}` Match a whitespace char and 6-8 digits
- `\s?` Match an optional whitespace char
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vXd6HR/1)

Example code

```
Dim s As String = "OK THT PHP This is it 06222021"
Dim result As String = Regex.Replace(s, "^\w{0,2}\s\w{0,3}\s\w{0,3}\s(.*?)\s\d{6,8}\s?$", "$1")
Console.WriteLine(result)
```

Output

```
This is it
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach does not work with groups and does use a Replace operation. The match itself yields the desired result.

It uses look-around expressions. To find a pattern between two other patterns, you can use the general form

```
(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)
```

This will only return `find` as match, excluding prefix and suffix.

If we insert your expressions, we get

```
(?<=\w{0,2}\s\w{0,3}\s\w{0,3}\s).*?(?=\s\d{6}\s?)
```

where I simplified `(\s|)` as `\s?`. We can also drop it completely, since we don't care about trailing spaces.

```
(?<=\w{0,2}\s\w{0,3}\s\w{0,3}\s).*?(?=\s\d{6})
```

Note that this works also if we have more than 6 digits because regex stops searching after it has found 6 digits and doesn't care about what follows.

This also gives a match if other things precede our pattern like in `123 OK THT PHP This is it 06222021`. We can exclude such results by specifying that the search must start at the beginning of the string with `^`.

If the exact length of the words and numbers does not matter, we simply write

```
(?<=^\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s).*?(?=\s\d+)
```

If the `find` part can contain numbers, we must specify that we want to match until the end of the line with `$` (and include a possible space again).

```
(?<=^\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s).*?(?=\s\d+\s?$)
```

Finally, we use a quantifier for the 3 ocurrences of word-space:

```
(?<=^(\w+\s){3}).*?(?=\s\d+\s?$)
```

This is compact and will only return `This is it` or `Get this content`.

```cs
string result = Regex.Match(@"(?<=^(\w+\s){3}).*?(?=\s\d+\s?$)").Value;
```